# Tried to listen value outside the widget tree? Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am using providers in two classes one is working fine while the other is not. I have initialized the provider in my main.dart file as follows

#### P.S (PersonalPostingService is a chopper service) but it works fine in the other class

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
        create: (_) => PersonalPostingService.create(),
        dispose: (context, PersonalPostingService service) =>
            service.client.dispose(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: WeeklyData(),
        ));
  }
```

#### I get the following error while calling a function using the provider

```
E/flutter (16561): This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
E/flutter (16561): Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.
E/flutter (16561):
E/flutter (16561): To fix, write:
E/flutter (16561): Provider.of<PersonalPostingService>(context, listen: false);
E/flutter (16561):
E/flutter (16561): It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the
E/flutter (16561): event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.
E/flutter (16561):
E/flutter (16561): The context used was: FormClass
```

#### This is where I am calling the provider (Statlesswidget Class)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Send"),
            onPressed: () async {
              await Provider.of<PersonalPostingService>(context)
                  .postPersonal(data);
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### If I add Listen:false, it just does this

```
Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1906 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Error launching application on vivo 1906.
Exited (sigterm)
```